# Angularjs : How to configure each module for routing

Tags: angularjs, module, url-routing

If I have to configure each module for routing what is the best way?

Comment: just use `.config` individually in each module! Whats the trouble?

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as this:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
       .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
           // Do the routing here.
       }])
```

You can do the same for each module, instead of maintaining routes for all modules in a single common file.